# Scripting in Spotfire to match Excel File input with Data Tables in database

Tags: excel, ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to introduce a diary on Spotfire that will **allow users to input Item IDs into a Microsoft Excel file** that will be linked to the Spotfire Data Connection to **search for additional information of the items they are searching for**. (e.g. Users searching for *Location, quantity or process of the item based on database data in Spotfire* after inserting the Item name into the linked Excel file). The Excel file is used such that my ***database information from Spotfire doesn't refresh alongside the database, but will keep information consistent with the Item IDs in the Excel file***

I was told that I would be scripting the linking process without any help or training hence would need help. The flow would look like this:

[image: Flowchart]

The **Excel File 's main tab** where the Spotfire Analyst will read the column goes like this:
[image: Excel Tab]

Ideally in Spotfire, the analyst will read the entries of the items (From *Cells **B2** down*) and match the Item ID with the ones in the Database. Thereafter, the dashboard on **Spotfire will show the 2 columns from the Excel file as well as additional columns containing all the information related to the Item ID extracted from the database.**

*Ideally, the dashboard on Spotfire will look like this table*:
[image: Spotfire Ideal Result]

The columns in green are the ones that will imported from the Excel File into Spotfire, while the rest of the information are derived from the database linked to Spotfire

I'm unsure of how to proceed or how to script, and most importantly how to start to make the link between the Excel file and Spotfire work. I would appreciate any form of advice or help... Thank you :>